# Java Mac HMAC vs C++ OpenSSL hmac

Tags: java, c++, openssl, hmac, hmacsha1

This is going to be a long question but I have a really weird bug. I use OpenSSL in C++ to compute a HMAC and compare them to a simular implementation using javax.crypto.Mac. For some keys the HMAC calculation is correct and for others there is a difference in HMAC. I believe the problem occurs when the keys get to big. Here are the details.

Here is the most important code for C++:

```
void computeHMAC(std::string message, std::string key){
    unsigned int digestLength = 20;
    HMAC_CTX hmac_ctx_;
    BIGNUM* key_ = BN_new();;

    BN_hex2bn(&key_, key); 

    unsigned char convertedKey[BN_num_bytes(key_)];
    BIGNUM* bn = BN_new();

    HMAC_CTX_init(&hmac_ctx_);

    BN_bn2bin(bn, convertedKey);
    int length = BN_bn2bin(key_, convertedKey);

    HMAC_Init_ex(&hmac_ctx_, convertedKey, length, EVP_sha1(), NULL);

/*Calc HMAC */
    std::transform( message.begin(), message.end(), message.begin(), ::tolower);
    unsigned char digest[digestLength];

    HMAC_Update(&hmac_ctx_, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(message.c_str()),
      message.length());
    HMAC_Final(&hmac_ctx_, digest, &digestLength);
    char mdString[40];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);
    }
     std::cout << "\n\nMSG:\n" << message << "\nKEY:\n" + std::string(BN_bn2hex(key_)) + "\nHMAC\n" + std::string(mdString) + "\n\n";
}
```

The java test looks like this:

```
public String calculateKey(String msg, String key) throws Exception{

    HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");

    BigInteger k = new BigInteger(key, 16);

    HMAC.init(new SecretKeySpec(k.toByteArray(), "HmacSHA1"));

    msg = msg.toLowerCase();
    HMAC.update(msg.getBytes());
    byte[] digest = HMAC.doFinal();

    System.out.println("Key:\n" + k.toString(16) + "\n");
    System.out.println("HMAC:\n" + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest).toLowerCase() + "\n");

    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest).toLowerCase();
}
```

Some test runs with different keys (all strings are interpreted as hex):

---

Key1:
736A66B29072C49AB6DC93BB2BA41A53E169D14621872B0345F01EBBF117FCE48EEEA2409CFC1BD92B0428BA0A34092E3117BEB4A8A14F03391C661994863DAC1A75ED437C1394DA0741B16740D018CA243A800DA25311FDFB9CA4361743E8511E220B79C2A3483FCC29C7A54F1EB804481B2DC87E54A3A7D8A94253A60AC77FA4584A525EDC42BF82AE2A1FD6E3746F626E0AFB211F6984367B34C954B0E08E3F612590EFB8396ECD9AE77F15D5222A6DB106E8325C3ABEA54BB59E060F9EA0

Msg:
test

Hmac OpenSSL:
b37f79df52afdbbc4282d3146f9fe7a254dd23b3

Hmac Java Mac:
b37f79df52afdbbc4282d3146f9fe7a254dd23b3

---

Key 2: 636A66B29072C49AB6DC93BB2BA41A53E169D14621872B0345F01EBBF117FCE48EEEA2409CFC1BD92B0428BA0A34092E3117BEB4A8A14F03391C661994863DAC1A75ED437C1394DA0741B16740D018CA243A800DA25311FDFB9CA4361743E8511E220B79C2A3483FCC29C7A54F1EB804481B2DC87E54A3A7D8A94253A60AC77FA4584A525EDC42BF82AE2A1FD6E3746F626E0AFB211F6984367B34C954B0E08E3F612590EFB8396ECD9AE77F15D5222A6DB106E8325C3ABEA54BB59E060F9EA0

Msg:
test

Hmac OpenSSL:
bac64a905fa6ae3f7bf5131be06ca037b3b498d7

Hmac Java Mac:
bac64a905fa6ae3f7bf5131be06ca037b3b498d7

---

Key 3: 836A66B29072C49AB6DC93BB2BA41A53E169D14621872B0345F01EBBF117FCE48EEEA2409CFC1BD92B0428BA0A34092E3117BEB4A8A14F03391C661994863DAC1A75ED437C1394DA0741B16740D018CA243A800DA25311FDFB9CA4361743E8511E220B79C2A3483FCC29C7A54F1EB804481B2DC87E54A3A7D8A94253A60AC77FA4584A525EDC42BF82AE2A1FD6E3746F626E0AFB211F6984367B34C954B0E08E3F612590EFB8396ECD9AE77F15D5222A6DB106E8325C3ABEA54BB59E060F9EA0

Msg:
test

Hmac OpenSSL:
c189c637317b67cee04361e78c3ef576c3530aa7

Hmac Java Mac:
472d734762c264bea19b043094ad0416d1b2cd9c

As the data shows, when the key gets to big, an error occurs. If have no idea which implementation is faulty. I have also tried with bigger keys and smaller keys. I haven't determined the exact threshold. Can anyone spot the problem? Is there anyone capable of telling me which HMAC is incorrect in the last case by doing a simulation using different software or can anyone tell me which 3rd implementation I could use to check mine?

Kind regards,

Roel Storms

Comment: I think the problem is not in the length of the key, but in its sign. Can you try to replace the beginning byte of one of the short keys that work with an "FF" and see if you get different results between C++ and Java?

Comment: So replace 83 by FF for example?

Comment: Doing so still results in a different HMAC.
Openssl: 53e8fab89762b945f08d245f963aab72dfd47533
Java : 15996db38398cb114f73f81645d7bbb87b24c2e4

Comment: No, I asked about replacing one that **works**, like the first or the second, and see if that "breaks" it. Like replace `73` with `FF` in the first.

Comment: Even shorter keys seem to have the same problem when using FF.
Another weird thing is that some keys (FF0AC77FAEFB8396ECD9AE77F15D5222A6DB106E8325C3ABEA54BB59E060F9EA0 for example) get printed in the java version with a leading 0 or even two leading 0's (like so: 0FF0AC77FAEFB8396ECD9AE77F15D5222A6DB106E8325C3ABEA54BB59E060F9EA0)

Comment: RealSkeptic, the 3 keys are all the same except for the first character (6,7,8)
Replacing FF in al 3 results in the same key. The key generated by replacing the first byte by FF results in the HMAC's in my 2nd comment.

Comment: Yes, then it's definitely a sign problem. I'll try to explain in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert a hexadecimal string to a `BigInt` in Java, it assumes the number is positive (unless the string includes a `-` sign).

But the internal representation of it is twos-complement. Meaning that one bit is used for the sign.

If you are converting a value that starts with a hex between `00` and `7F` inclusive, then that's not a problem. It can convert the byte directly, because the leftmost bit is zero, which means that the number is considered positive.

But if you are converting a value that starts with `80` through `FF`, then the leftmost bit is 1, which will be considered negative. To avoid this, and keep the `BigInteger` value exactly as it is supplied, it adds another zero byte at the beginning.

So, internally, the conversion of a number such as `7ABCDE` is the byte array

```
0x7a 0xbc 0xde
```

But the conversion of a number such as `FABCDE` (only the first byte is different!), is:

```
0x00 0xfa 0xbc 0xde
```

This means that for keys that begin with a byte in the range 80-FF, the `BigInteger.toByteArray()` is not producing the same array that your C++ program produced, but an array one byte longer.

There are several ways to work around this - like using your own hex-to-byte-array parser or finding an existing one in some library. If you want to use the one produced by `BigInteger`, you could do something like this:

```
BigInteger k = new BigInteger(key, 16);
byte[] kByteArr = k.toByteArray();
if ( kByteArr.length > (key.length() + 1) / 2 ) {
    kByteArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(kByteArr,1,kByteArr.length);
}
```

Now you can use the `kByteArr` to perform the operation properly.

Another issue you should watch out for is keys whose length is odd. In general, you shouldn't have a hex octet string that has an odd length. A string like `F8ACB` is actually `0F8ACB` (which is not going to cause an extra byte in BigInteger) and should be interpreted as such. This is why I wrote `(key.length() + 1)` in my formula - if key is odd-length, it should be interpreted as a one octet longer. This is also important to watch out for if you write your own hex-to-byte-array converter - if the length is odd, you should add a zero at the beginning before you start converting.

Comment: I am going to test this tomorrow since I have to go now but you can describe the behavior perfectly so I assume this is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. If I understand correctly, your code is checking if the length of the produced array is correct. If this is not the case it will copy the bytearray from character 1 untill the end of the array thereby shortening it by 1 byte?
I noticed the leading 0's before but I thought it didn't matter since they were LEADING 0's.

Comment: @RoelStorms Yes, exactly. Leading zeros are not important when you look at the data as a "number". But when you look at the data as just data - to be encrypted and decrypted - then zero is a legitimate piece of data (think of a black pixel, for example).